# Why does this statement give an error?

Tags: c

The compiler gives an error on this statement.
`i>=3?b=10:b=5;`

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Not able to figure out why. Compiler being used is GCC.

Comment: Try moving the `b=` out to the front.

Comment: There's no virtue in using the `?:` operator when an `if` statement would work perfectly well: `if (i >= 3) { b = 10; } else { b = 5; }`

Comment: If it can be naturally expressed by `?:` operator, it is in my opinion preferable over `if` statement. In this case the `b = i >= 3 ? 10 : 5;` would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is explained by operator precedence. In accordance with C grammar your

```
 i >= 3 ? b = 10 : b = 5;
```

is interpreted by C compiler as

```
 (i >= 3 ? b = 10 : b) = 5;
```

Firstly, this is probably not what you intended. Secondly, in C language the result of `?:` operator is not an lvalue. You cannot assign anything to it. Hence the error message.

In order to correct the problem (assuming I understand your intent correctly), you either have to use braces

```
 i >= 3 ? (b = 10) : (b = 5);
```

or simply rewrite it in a more conventional way

```
 b = i >= 3 ? 10 : 5;
```

---

As a side note, this happens to be one of the differences between C and C++ grammar. In C++ your original statement would be interpreted as `i >= 3 ? (b = 10) : (b = 5)` even without explicit braces. On top of that, in C++ the result of `?:` can be an lvalue.

In other words, in C++ your original statement would compile and work "as intended", but not in C.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like:

```
b = (i >= 3) ? 10 : 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to have expressions, not statements, in the `?:` operator's two execution paths.

Comment: `b = 10` *is* an expression, as is `b = 5`. He doesn't have any "statements" in his `?:` operator.